# How to correctly handle returning to screen?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have the next sequence:

- create activity;
- place a fragment into it;
- go to next fragment;
- return to previous fragment with back button.

Okay, let's do it.

This is how I go to next fragment in navigation:

```java
public static void addFragment(Fragment currentFragment, Fragment fragment, int frameLayout) {
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = currentFragment.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(frameLayout, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

public static void replaceFragment(Fragment currentFragment, Fragment fragment, int frameLayout) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = currentFragment.getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment topFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(frameLayout);
    int transactionsCount = fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
    if (transactionsCount > 0 && topFragment == currentFragment) {
        fragmentManager.popBackStack();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(frameLayout, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }   else {
        fragmentTransaction.replace(frameLayout, fragment);
    }
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

In `onCreateView` of first fragment I load some data and hide activity indicator when it's done

```java
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LinearLayout homeLayout = new LinearLayout(activity);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.screen_home, homeLayout);

    setupCategoryButtons();
    setupHomeGenderRadioButton(mainLayout);
    setupMagazinesPreviews(mainLayout);

    return homeLayout;
}

private void setupCategoryButtons() {
    if(categoriesButtons.size() > 0) {
        View categoriesWaitIndicator = activity.findViewById(R.id.categoriesWaitIndicator);
        categoriesWaitIndicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        LinearLayout categoriesButtonsLayout = (LinearLayout)activity.findViewById(R.id.categoryButtonsLayout);

        for(CategoryButton categoryButton : categoriesButtons) {
            categoriesButtonsLayout.addView(categoryButton);
        }

        refreshCategoriesButtons();
    }
}
```

Nothing special. And it works perfectly. Until I return to this screen.

When I return to this screen I getting `NullPointerException` on those lines:

```java
categoriesWaitIndicator.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
categoriesButtonsLayout.addView(categoryButton);
```

It seems that the app cannot find those views! I tried to do it in `onResume` but it has the same effect. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what this fragment does, but it's manipulating views in the `Activity`.  Since it's possible for the fragment to exist before the `Activity` view is built or destroyed, it could be trying to get views that have been destroyed and/or modified by elements beyond its control.  It would be much better if the fragment was isolated so it handled it's own view.